# Formatting of foreach-generated formulas

Tags: equations, align, foreach

I'm new to Latex and have a background in software development. I find the ability of auto-generating formulas and lists impressive, but struggle to format the result properly as the letters are slightly too big. Please excuse I'm not familiar with the differences of elements as I'm still very much working on trial and error.

How would I define custom font-sizing for these loop-generated equations?

This here is my document which does work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\def\square[#1]{#1^2}
\gdef\squareresult{}%
\foreach \i in {0,...,6}{%
    \FPeval\A{\square[i]}%
    \FPeval\A{round(A:0)}%
    \xappto\squareresult{ \pmb{\A} = \i^2 = \i \cdot \i \\ }%
}%

\begin{document}

   \begin{align*}
    \squareresult 
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

How I see Latex seems to have issues using `\begin{equation} \squareresult \end{equation}` with foreach-loops (in this case there is no newline after each formula). Using `gather*` instead of `align*` seems to be a working option too, but frankly I wouldn't know which one is preferred -and why.
Some sources suggest using `\[ \textstyle` (or other styles) - which I was not able to make work in this setup, as it appears to be only working on `equation`.

In general: Are there preferred ways to properly do a foreach-loop with a linebreak after each line and applying a specific styleset to it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\noexpand\bm` instead of `\pmb` (load the `bm` package after `mathtools`).

However, you can do much better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\showexpr}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = evaluation, #2 = output format, #3 = start, #4 = end
  \qohelet_showexpr:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__qohelet_lines_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \qohelet_showexpr:nnnn
 {
  % the function to evaluate the expression according to the given template
  \cs_set:Nn \__qohelet_eval:n { \fp_eval:n { #1 } }
  % an alias for the second argument
  \cs_set_eq:NN \eval \__qohelet_eval:n
  % the function to print the output according to the given template
  \cs_set:Nn \__qohelet_output:n { #2 }
  % clear the sequence where we store the lines
  \seq_clear:N \l__qohelet_lines_seq
  % loop in the given range
  \int_step_inline:nnn { #3 } { #4 }
   {
    % add the corresponding line for the current value ##1
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__qohelet_lines_seq { \__qohelet_output:n { ##1 } }
   }
  % output the results
  \begin{align*}
  \seq_use:Nn \l__qohelet_lines_seq { \\ }
  \end{align*}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\showexpr
  {#1^2}
  {\bm{#1^2}&=\eval{#1}=#1\cdot#1}
  {0}{6}

\showexpr
  {#1^2-2*#1+3}
  {#1^2-2\cdot#1+3&=\eval{#1}}
  {1}{4}

\showexpr
  {round(sqrt(#1),4)}
  {\sqrt{#1}&=\eval{#1}}
  {1}{6}

\end{document}
```

The first argument to `\showexpr` is the expression to evaluate, using a fairly natural syntax. The second argument is the template for the output, where `\eval{#1}` stands for the computed result. The third and fourth arguments are the starting and ending point of the range.

Note that in both the first and second argument `#1` stands for the current value in the loop.

With `\seq_use:Nn` we ensure that a blank line is not added at the end, which happens with your code (even if fixed with `\noexpand`).

[image]